# Past train punctuality data for Deutsche Bahn

Tags: trains, germany, deutsche-bahn

Is there a way how one can check the punctuality of Deutsche Bahn trains for dates in the past? I am looking for information about specific trains.

Comment: you can find statistics, but are you searching for the actual times of specific trains?

Comment: Here is one data point: over the last few years more than  half of the trains I took had operational problems: cancelled, delayed,  less cars than planned, overcrowded, extra/missing stops, etc. This being said, I don't live there so that's about 20-30 trips

Comment: I am looking for information about specific trains.

Comment: @MartinPeters Which train is it (train number like ICE594)? I can give you a link for the past data!

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at [zugfinder.net](https://www.zugfinder.net). It comes in a free and a paid version. For the free version you can see the data you need for the last month only. Simply enter the train number or station in the search fields on the left.

Answer (score 3):

Not a direct answer, but a few avenues to explore further:

- DB has an [open data portal](https://data.deutschebahn.com) with [datasets](https://data.deutschebahn.com/dataset.groups.datasets.html) and [API's](https://data.deutschebahn.com/dataset.groups.apis.html) although it seems to be outdated.
- [The question "*Are there public transport data for Germany freely available?*" on OpenData.SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/966/9127)
- If you can get your hands on GTFS-RT (real time) data of DB, you should be able to see how much delay each vehicle has. By storing that data periodically (or finding someone who has done so already) you can build a history and do analysis on that.

  - Unfortunately this data seems not readily available. The [Mobility Database](https://database.mobilitydata.org/) for example has [a wide array of links to GTFS-RT data](https://github.com/MobilityData/mobility-database-catalogs/tree/main/catalogs/sources/gtfs/realtime), but it's missing data for Germany. If you find something, please do post that as an answer.
  - Interestingly [Motis](https://motis-project.de/), an open source multi-modal trip planner, shows info on real time positions of public transport vehicles in their [routeplanner](https://europe.motis-project.de/#/). Perhaps you can find where they pull this data from on [their Github](https://github.com/motis-project/motis).